# MySQL query with non-printing characters (left-to-right mark)

Tags: mysql, unicode

I just found myself lost in the interesting situation that I need to query MySQL for fields containing a so called [Left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).

As the nature of this character is to be non-printing, thus invisible, I'm unable to simply copy/paste it into a query.

As mentioned in the linked Wikipedia article, the Left-to-right mark is Unicode character U+200F, which is a fact that I'm sure is the key to success in my current adventure.

My question is: How do I use raw Unicode in a MySQL query? Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%\U+200F%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username REGEXP '\U+200F'
```

or whatever the correct syntax for Unicode in MySQL is and depending on whether this is supported with `LIKE` and/or `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a unicode char, something like this should work:

```
SELECT CHAR(<number> USING utf8);
```

Also, don't use `REGEXP`, because the regexp lib used by MySQL is very old, and doesn't support multi-byte charsets.

Comment: Thanks! This led me in the right direction. I don't know why I didn't think about using `CHAR`, while I was happily using `ORD` to get the charcode of this mysterious character.

I ended up doing something like: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(14844047), '%')`

`14844047` being the charcode of the ltr-mark I got from `ORD`.